# Asymptotics of a nonautonomous linear dynamical system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm interested in the limits $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}A\left(t\right),\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}B\left(t\right),$$ of the system
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}A\left(t\right)=p_{A}\left(1-A-B\right)\\
\frac{d}{dt}B\left(t\right)=\left(p_{B}+q_{B}\right)\left(1-A-B\right)-q_{B}\left(1-B\right)e^{-\left(p_{A}+p_{B}\right)t}
\end{cases}$$
with initial conditions $A(0)=B(0)=0$, where $p_{A},p_{B},q_{B}>0$ are constants.

Since most of what I know about critical points of dynamical systems concerns autonomous ones, I thought about investigating the following autonomous system:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}A\left(t\right)=p_{A}\left(1-A-B\right)\\
\frac{d}{dt}B\left(t\right)=\left(p_{B}+q_{B}\right)\left(1-A-B\right)-q_{B}\left(1-B\right)C\left(t\right)\\
\frac{d}{dt}C\left(t\right)=-\left(p_{A}+p_{B}\right)C\left(t\right)
\end{cases}$$
where $C(0)=1$. Setting the left hand sides to zero results in the conditions
$$A+B =1,C =0,$$
which means there's an infinite number of critical points, which is the set
$$\left\{ \left(a,1-a,0\right)|a\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

My question is, is there some way to find the critical point towards the solution converges to?

My attempts at solving said system have failed (other than when $q_{B}=0$, which is a special but simpler case), and I'm hoping there's some other method of finding the limits, that don't require completely solving the system.

Any thoughts would be appreciated on the matter,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is a linear time-varying system. We do not expect to have a closed-form solution, but did you try with math software, e.g., Alfa?

Comment: @Arastas I did find the limits numerically, and am able to numerically find the solution as well. Finding a full closed form solution would be great, but as you stated, it's not likely feasible. I am wondering though, if a formula for the limits could be attained (without trying to find a closed form solution).

Comment: what model is the system for?

Comment: @BlackMild This is a model of the diffusion of 2 competitive products (denoted by A and B) on the 1D line. The parameters $p_{A}$,$p_{B}$ represent external influence and the parameter $q_{B}$ represents internal influence among B-adopters. It is assumed in this model that $q_{A}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ascertain, first, whether the system converges to an equilibrium for the regime of parameters and initial condition proposed. Assuming that it converges, it might be hard to obtain a closed form expression for this limit as a function of the vector of parameters and initial condition.

Below, I prove that it attains equilibrium (Claim 3).

**Remark.** I will write $x(t)$ instead of $A(t)$ and $y(t)$ instead of $B(t)$.

**Claim 1.**[*Invariant set*] $\mathcal{I}=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,(x\geq 0)\,\wedge\,(x+y\leq 1)\right\}$ is invariant w.r.t. the underlying dynamics.

This is quite straightforward to check.

Claim 1 is relevant to proving Claim 2.

**Claim 2.** [*Attractor*] Any orbit with initial condition in $\mathcal{I}$ is attracted to the line $\mathcal{A}=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\,x+y=1\right\}$. That is, $d(z(t),\mathcal{A})\overset{t\rightarrow +\infty}\longrightarrow 0$ whenever $z(0)=(x(0),y(0))\in \mathcal{I}$ and $z(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is solution to the ODE.

*Proof.* Indeed, define $w(t)\overset{\Delta}=(1-x(t)-y(t))$, and you have

$$\dot{w}(t)=-\widetilde{p} w(t)-q_B(1-y(t))e^{-(p_A+p_B)t}\leq -(\widetilde{p}+q_Be^{-(p_A+p_B)t})w(t)\leq -\widetilde{p}w(t),$$

where $\widetilde{p}=p_A+p_B+q_B$; the first inequality above holds since $x(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$ and the second inequality holds since $w(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$. These are the case as we are choosing $(x(0),y(0))\in \mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ is invariant (here is where the invariance is important).

Now, you get that $w(t)\leq e^{-\widetilde{p}t}$, in view of Gronwall's inequality, i.e., $w(t)\overset{t\rightarrow +\infty}\longrightarrow 0$ exponentially fast, which implies that $\mathcal{A}$ is an attractor with Basin of attraction containing $\mathcal{I}$.

Claims 1 and 2 yield the following.

**Claim 3.** [*System attains an equilibrium*] Let $z(0)\in \mathcal{I}$. Then, $z(t)\overset{t\rightarrow +\infty}\longrightarrow v$ for some $v\in \mathcal{A}$.

*Proof.* Indeed, remark that $\dot{x}(t)=p_A w(t)\geq 0$ since $\mathcal{I}$ is invariant (Claim 1). This implies that $x(t)$ is monotonous increasing for solutions with initial condition at $\mathcal{I}$. Claim 2 implies $\dot{x}(t)\longrightarrow 0$. To grant $x(t)\longrightarrow a$ for some $a$, we just need to guarantee that $\dot{x}(t)$ is integrable, i.e., $\int_{0}^{\infty} \dot{x}(s)ds<\infty$. But, this holds since $w(t)$ is bounded by an exponential as shown in Claim 2 (hence $\dot{x}(t)$ is bounded by an exponential, as well). Now, since $d(z(t),\mathcal{A})\longrightarrow 0$ and $x(t)\longrightarrow a$ for some $a$, we have that $y(t)\longrightarrow b$ for some $b$ with $(a,b)\in \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the Laplace Transform to the odes with null initial conditions we obtain

$$
\cases{
(s+p_A) \hat A(s)+p_A \hat B(s)-\frac{p_A}{s}=0\\
\hat A(s) (p_B+q_B)-q_B \hat B(s+p_A+p_B)+(s + p_B+q_B)\hat B(s)+\frac{q_B}{s+p_A+p_B}-\frac{p_B}{s}-\frac{q_B}{s}=0
}
$$

and solving for $\hat A(s),\hat B(s)$ we obtain

$$
\cases{
\hat A(s) = \frac 1s\left(\frac{p_A (s+p_A+p_B+q_B-q_B (s+p_A+p_B) \hat B(s+p_A+p_B))}{(s+p_A+p_B)
   (s+p_A+p_B+q_B)}\right)\\
\hat B(s) = \frac 1s\left(\frac{p_B}{s+p_A+p_B}+\frac{q_B (s+p_A)
   \hat B(s+p_A+p_B)}{s+p_A+p_B+q_B}\right)
}
$$

now assuming stability, given the nature of the operators involved, we can apply the Laplace final value theorem which states that

$$
\cases{
A(\infty) = \lim_{s\to 0}s\hat A(s)\\
B(\infty) = \lim_{s\to 0}s\hat B(s)
}
$$

so we have

$$
\cases{
A(\infty) =\frac{p_A (p_A+p_B+q_B-q_B (p_A+p_B) \gamma)}{(p_A+p_B)
   (p_A+p_B+q_B)}\\
B(\infty) = \frac{p_B}{p_A+p_B}+\frac{q_B p_A
   \gamma}{p_A+p_B+q_B}
}
$$

Here remains to know the value for $\gamma=\hat B(p_A+p_B)$. Trivial cases are $q_B = 0$ or $p_A=0$.